# silverlight commands via prism, getting the event args for the event?

Tags: silverlight, prism, dataform, icommand

I've a data form in SL3 which uses Prisms Commands with Attached Behaviour for trapping events.

(It fairly tightly follows this blog post:
http://blogs.southworks.net/dschenkelman/2009/04/18/commands-with-attached-behavior-for-silverlight-3-dataform/#comment-607)

Basically, it's all hooked up and working fine, however in the viewmodel, I can't see how I can access the event args for the event.

In the constructor of the VM I define the delegate command:

```
this.EditEnded = new DelegateCommand<object>(o => {
    //how can I tell if the button clicked was cancel or save?
}
```

But I need access to the DataFormItemEditEndedEventArgs property to so I can define what needs to be done? I want to perform different actions depending if the user cancelled or committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the parameter back, you could edit your CommandBehaviorBase derived class like this:

```
private void ItemEditEnded(object sender, DataFormItemEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
     this.CommandParameter = e.EditAction;
     ExecuteCommand();
}
```

This would send the EditAction (or whatever else you want) to the CommandDelegate.  In this case, you would *not* add an attached property for the parameter.  Edit your attached property class appropriately (leave out the CommandParameter).  I'm not in love with this approach (seems kinda non-standard), and I wonder if someone else has an alternate suggestion.

I mean, you could always add events for the different kinds of events (one for commit, etc.), and that's a little more pure, but it would mean a lot of extra code.  You could get away with it in this instance, but for other events, it would become impossible (communicating mouse coordinates or something ridiculous).

My [video on Prism Commands](http://development-guides.silverbaylabs.org/Video/Prism-Commands). deals with more static parameters   See the "Command Parameters" section for how to sort out the methods based a static attached property.

```
<Button Content="Save"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        cal:Click.Command="{Binding GetCompanyData}"
        cal:Click.CommandParameter="SaveButton"
        />
```

Comment: Hi Erik, I've already seen your screencast, it was an enomous help in me getting this far. I still don't see how this can be used to get the event args however? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I answered too quickly.  I've provided an alternate suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should declare seperate Commands (SaveCommand and CancelCommand) for seperate buttons and actions.